# HAproxy forward proxy with SSL termination

Tags: ssl, proxy, haproxy, openssl, curl

#### Problem:

Iam trying to build a forward proxy with ssl termination, further it upstreams to my proxy servers eg: TOR. My upstream proxy services are non-https.

Client -> Network-Haproxy -> Uptstream-Proxy -> Internet

I could easily succeed in `tcp` mode of HAproxy without ssl termination, but when I terminate ssl and forward, things don't work.

#### Steps Followed:

I followed the below steps to generate self-certified ssl certificates.

```sh
$ openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -extensions v3_ca -keyout haproxy-ca-key.pem -out haproxy-ca-cert.pem -subj "/C=GB/ST=London/L=London/O=Global Security/OU=IT Department/CN=example.com"
```

combined them for creating final `.pem` file

```sh
$ cat haproxy-ca-cert.pem haproxy-ca-key.pem >> mysite.pem
```

The above file is used in my `haproxy.cfg` for ssl termination.

```sh
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
    #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256::RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

    stats enable
    stats uri /stats
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats auth user:password


frontend www.mysite.com
    mode http
    bind 0.0.0.0:8443
    bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /home/ubuntu/haproxy/mysite.pem crt-ignore-err all
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    default_backend web_servers

backend web_servers
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    server server1 xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx #my upstream server which is not ssl protected
```

When I try to curl from my client machine to use the above proxy I get following error.

```sh
$ curl -k --proxy https://my-haproxy-server:443 --cacert haproxy-ca-cert.pem  https://httpbin.org/ip -vvv
*   Trying my-haproxy-server...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my-haproxy-server (my-haproxy-server) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

If you have read the `cfg` file, you can see I have redirected `:8443` to `:443`, so I can send request to non `https` proxy, but that too doesn't work

```sh
$ curl -k --proxy http://my-haproxy-server:8443 --cacert haproxy-ca-cert.pem  https://httpbin.org/ip -vvv
*   Trying my-haproxy-server...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my-haproxy-server (my-haproxy-server) port 8443 (#0)
* allocate connect buffer!
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to httpbin.org:443
> CONNECT httpbin.org:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: httpbin.org:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< content-length: 0
< location: https://httpbin.org:443/
< cache-control: no-cache
< connection: close
< 
* Received HTTP code 302 from proxy after CONNECT
* CONNECT phase completed!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 302 from proxy after CONNECT
```

> Any lead would be appreciated.

#### Extra Info:

- HAPROXY: HA-Proxy version 2.0.13-1ppa1~bionic 2020/02/15 - https://haproxy.org/
- OPENSSL: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
- CURL: curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1 zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3